# Updating Twilio MediaUrl for use with Express 4

Tags: express, twilio

I am updating my twilio sms messaging tool to use express 4.  On one one line of code I am having an issue.

```
var mediaUrl = request.param('MediaUrl' + i); //deprecated in express 4
```

When I attempt to update with this line

```
var mediaUrl = request.query.MediaUrl + i;
```

it no longer links to the twilio MediaURL.  Here is the complete code for reference.

```
var numMedia = parseInt( request.body.NumMedia );
if (numMedia > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < numMedia; i++) {

        //var mediaUrl = request.query.MediaUrl + i;
        var mediaUrl = request.param('MediaUrl' + i); //deprecated in express 4

        groupRef.where( {"memberNumber":request.query.From} ).limit(1).on( "value", function ( data ){
            if( data.count() ){
                data.forEach( function( snapshot ){
                    var member = snapshot.value();
                    messagesRef.push({
                        sid: request.body.MessageSid,
                        type:'text',
                        tstamp: new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: "America/Denver" }),
                        fromName:member.memberName,
                        fromNumber:request.body.From,
                        message:"",
                        media:mediaUrl,
                        groupNumber:request.body.To
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is due to the fact that Twilio is POSTing the data to you and `request.query` is looking in the querystring. Either change the Twilio method to GET, or use [`req.body`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body) to get the value from the POST.

The simple fix would be to use:

```
var mediaUrl = request.body.MediaUrl + i;
```

Comment: the req.body now gets the mediaURL.  still having some issues with using the URL after getting it.  But that is a different problem to solve.  Thanks

Comment: I'm glad this has helped you and thank you for marking my answer as accepted. Please note that since you have edited the question to incorporate the answer, it could be confusing for future visitors.

Comment: I put it back as original.  Thanks for the correction